# File soldering tip to fit in soldering iron

Tags: soldering

I'm sorry for my english, I don't know how to say it better, but it's not actually the tip like in the end- it's the part of it that goes into the soldering iron. That part - can I file it so it fits in my soldering iron? There's a store near my house with a soldering iron and a tip I needed. And I have a soldering station. But the tip is ticker than my soldering iron can have. So I thought on the file idea, so it would fit normally. But I wouldn't touch the end of the tip, only the part that goes into the soldering iron.

Would this be a good idea or would it still damage the tip somehow?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The plating gets damaged and corrosion will occur, but cleanable as thermal resistance rises. Go for it

Comment: As long as it's a solid tip -- there's an older model of Weller soldering irons that has a bit of steel engineered to lose magnetism at a controlled temperature, in conjunction with a magnetic switch inside the handle.  If you filed one of those too far, it'd fall apart.

Comment: I think the real need for the plating on a soldering iron is to keep the copper tip from dissolving in the solder -- you don't have to worry about that happening in the back end of the iron unless you're using it in a seriously non-standard way.

Comment: It might not work well due to poor thermal connection, but like the others said if the original is solid metal then it shouldn't be dangerous.

Comment: @TimWescott As I don't know much of soldering (I've been learning for a week various things about it because I only knew soldering iron + tin = stuff soldered), what do you mean with solid tip? Like, made of what? Also, I don't know what the tip is made of. I only know it looks like silver, at least from the outside (from one of the things I learned, that should be the coating, I believe). But I don't know what's bellow that. If this is what you meant.

Comment: @Drew Why do you say poor thermal connection? Because of being filing and it won't get as round as it is now? Or because of the corrosion Tony talked about? (that would be cleaned when I see there are problems with the temperature on the tip)

Comment: If you have to ask, you don't have that fancy an iron.  The tip is probably copper that's been plated with iron and then with tin.  Copper because it conducts heat well, iron because copper is soluable in solder, and tin because iron doesn't like to stick to solder, and you want a tip that solder will easily flow onto.

Comment: Nope, the iron was very cheap. I leave in a village, so not many things around haha. Was the easiest. I did it, and yes, it's copper. At least has its color. Then silver outside. After filing it and getting it hot on the iron, it even started to change colors (???). Another one from the same store (cheap things there only...), is golden. But was cheap too (never had seen a golden one)

So about the tin coating, isn't that what we need to do? Tips come coated with iron and then tin, not only iron? I thought they were coated with iron and we tinned them (sorry if I misunderstood what you said)